How to force an http request to run after another one in Angular19
I have two http requests i want to run after one another because one relies on the other generating a cookie first. How can i make sure the second one does not start until the first one finished?
it tried something like this:
loginbutton(){
method1();
method2();
}

with each containing a single request.

This question is similar to: RxJs combine http request. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

use the concatMap operator :
import { concatMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
    
    loginbutton() {
      this.method1().pipe(
        tap(() => console.log('Executing method1')),
        concatMap(() => {
          console.log('method1 completed, starting method2'); 
          return this.method2();
        }),
        tap(() => console.log('Executing method2'))
      ).subscribe({
        next: () => console.log('Both requests completed successfully'),
        error: (err) => console.error('Error occurred:', err)
      });
    }


Try adding an await keyword before the first method(the method that generates the cookie)
try {
    // Wait for method1 to finish
    await method1();
    // Then run method2
    await method2();
} catch (error) {
    console.error("An error occurred:", error);
}

